# Derivative the exponential map $e^A$

Tags: derivatives, definition, matrix-exponential

Can the derivative the map

$$
f(A) = e^A, A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$

be defined as

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{A+h\Delta} -e^{A}}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0} e^{A} \frac{e^{h\Delta} - I}{h}
$$

where $\Delta$ is an "increment matrix" of some form? Or maybe

$$
\lim_{\lVert \Delta \rVert \to 0} \frac{\lVert e^{A+\Delta} -e^{A} - f'(A) \rVert}{\lVert \Delta \rVert}
$$

I think the latter might make more sense (though not 100% sure)

Comment: For a smooth $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ at first only the directional derivative exists $D_v f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}$. It is linear in $v$. That is your first guess. Also for $f(A) = e^A$ you can look at the decomposition $A = B+N$ where $B= P D P^{-1},BN=NB,N^n = 0$ (consequence of the Jordan normal form). Then $f(A) = e^B e^N = P e^D P^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{N^k}{k!}$

Comment: For general $A, B$ it's not true that $\exp(A + B) = \exp A \exp B$, but it does hold if $A, B$ commute.

Comment: In theory in my case $e^A$ should represent a rotation matrix, so $A = -A^T$, we can retrieve the rotation matrix using the Rodriguez formula.

Comment: $A = -A^\top= -A^*$ means $A =P\Lambda P^*$ and if $\Delta = P \nu P^*$ with $\nu$ diagonal (or commuting with $\Lambda$) then $D_\Delta f(A) = P D_\nu f(\Lambda) P^*=P \nu e^{\Lambda} P^*$. When $\nu$ doesn't commute with $\Lambda$ there is no such simple expression

Comment: @reuns if you don't mind, please give a complete answer.

Comment: Did you prove what Travis said ? $e^z$ is defined by a power series, once $e^{z+s} = e^z e^s$ is true for complex numbers it is true also for $z,s$ in a (complete) normed commutative real algebra, but it doesn't hold when $zs \ne sz$

Comment: No, but I suppose I can use the power series definition of exponential of an operator + Cauchy product to get that result.